# Get all classes defined in module ruby

Tags: ruby, module, introspection

Is it possible to know all the classes defined inside a module in ruby.

```
module A
  class Klass
  end
  class Klass1
  end
end
```

Is there any ruby introspection method to get all the classes defined in module A?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find classes available in a Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833125/find-classes-available-in-a-module)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is one way

```
module A
  class Klass
  end
  X = 10
  module B;end
end

# Just to list the class(s) defined inside A
A.constants.select { |k| A.const_get(k).instance_of? Class } # => [:Klass]
```

Nice post to do the same in [recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9848153/how-do-you-find-all-modules-and-classes-within-a-module-recursively).

Comment: @Max You are right `instance_of?` came into mind on the first place. So used it.. :-)

Comment: Also doesn't work on modules/ classes etc. that have not yet been loaded.

Comment: @Dennis That is another problem domain. Constant loading in Ruby.

Comment: @ArupRakshit as this is clearly a dependency, it's worth noting.

Comment: @Dennis I don't know what you mean here. Can you try in IRB? Where are you testing this? What is not working? Any sample code to examine it?

Comment: @ArupRakshit if you put your sample code of `module A` in a separate file (make sure it's not loaded via require before calling constants) ruby does not know about the contents of the file, calling constants will not load the file or make the module inside visible for you.

Comment: @Dennis Ok then Ruby got changed probably a lot in that case from 2014.