# How does Object know about the const_get method?

Tags: ruby

I was reading [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833125/find-classes-available-in-a-module) with an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/833179/2909897) that mentions using the `Module#const_get` instance method to find a class in a module. For example:

```
module M
  class C
  end
end

p M.const_get 'C'
#=> M::C
```

I was curious about the `const_get` method so I used `ri` and found:

```
ri Module#const_get
...
This method will recursively look up constant names if a namespaced
class name is provided.  For example:

  module Foo; class Bar; end end
  Object.const_get 'Foo::Bar'
...
```

It seems like `Object::const_get` is a singleton method. Using it in our context works:

```
module M
  class C
  end
end

p Object.const_get 'M::C'
#=> M::C
```

But there's nothing documented about that singleton method:

```
ri Object::const_get
Nothing known about Object::const_get
ri Object.const_get
Nothing known about Object.const_get
```

This confused me because I know a `Module` is an `Object` but an `Object` is not a `Module`:

```
Module.ancestors
#=> [Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
Object.ancestors
#=> [Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Except then I used the `Object#is_a?` instance method to check and saw that I was wrong about that:

```
Module.is_a? Object
#=> true
Object.is_a? Module
#=> true
```

What started as an innocent `ri` query has led me to be confused about the entire Ruby object model.

- Why does `Object.is_a? Module #=> true` if `Module` is not in `Object`s ancestor chain?
- How does `Object` know about the `const_get` method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an artifact of the ill-understood separation between an object's class and an object's *singleton class*, a sort of shadow class that each class uses for things like this.

You can access this easily in Ruby 2.5+ with the `singleton_class` method:

```
Object.singleton_class.ancestors
# => [#<Class:Object>, #<Class:BasicObject>, Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Where `Module` makes an appearance here, so that's how those methods get mixed in and are callable via `Object`.

Object itself has a comparatively dull inheritance chain:

```
Object.ancestors
#=> [Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Every object in Ruby has a class, even `Class` is an `Object`, which also has an associated `Class`.

Comment: Ah! I think I was looking at the wrong ancestor chain! Looking at the ancestor chain for `Object` mislead me because `Object` is a class, so the ancestor chain will show which methods are available to instances of that class right? But `Object` also has a singleton class (like all objects), and checking that ancestor chain will show which methods are available to the actual object `Object`.

Comment: I like how you used `Object#singleton_class` that's what helped it click for me! Are you able to add a mention that about the two different ancestor chains, one for `Object` and one for `Object.new`? Checking `Object.singleton_class.ancestors` and `Object.new.singleton_class.ancestors` answers the question about `is_a?`

Answer (score 1):

I think your confusion stems from looking at `Object` from two directions at once:

1. `Object` is a class so `Object.ancestors` can be used to look at the inheritance hierarchy. This tells you that `Object < Kernel` is true and `Object < Module` is false.
2. Classes in Ruby are also objects, specifically they're instances of the `Class` class. This tells you that `Object.is_a? Class` and `Object.is_a? Module` in the same way that `'pancakes'.is_a? String`. And that `Object.const_get` is a method call in the same way that `'pancakes'.upcase` is a method call.

You can think of `some_obj.is_a? SomeClass` as a shorter way of saying `some_obj.class.ancestors.include? SomeClass`.

Answering your specific questions:

1. > Why does `Object.is_a? Module #=> true` if `Module` is not in `Object`'s ancestor chain?

   Because `is_a?` and `ancestors` are looking at different things.
2. > How does `Object` know about the `const_get` method?

   Because `Object` is an instance of the `Class` class and `Class` includes `Module` in its ancestors. Similarly to how `'pancakes'` is an instance of the `String` class which has `Kernel` in its ancestors so `'pancakes'` has an `object_id` method.

Answer (score 0):

#### `Object.is_a? Module #=> true`

`is_a?` is asking whether `Object` is an instance (or specialised instance) of `Module`. `Class` is a subclass of `Module` so all instances of `Class` are really just specialised instances of `Module`. Since `Object` is an instance of `Class`, it follows that `Object` is also an instance of `Module`.

#### `Module#const_get`

`const_get` is an instance method defined within the `Module` class. Since `Object` is an instance of `Module` (for reasons discussed above), it has access to `Module#const_get`.